# Control Whether Bootstrapdialog is Closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-dialog

Hello I want to refresh page when bootstrap dialog is closed.I tried to do but it refreshed page before bootstrap dialog is closed.A random id is assigned to bootstrap dialog so I could not use it also.I need help.

```
 var commentBox = BootstrapDialog.show({
            title: 'Comments',
            message: showComments(),
            buttons: [{
                label: 'Add Comment',
                action: function () { addComment(); },
            }, {
                label: 'Close',
                action: function (dialogItself) {
                    dialogItself.close();
                }
            }]
        });
```

Here is my bootstrap dialog. How can I control if it is closed. Thank you for any help.

Comment: I solved as below.

Comment: var commentBox = BootstrapDialog.show({
                title: 'Comments',
                message: showComments(),
                onhide: function(dialogRef){
                   location.reload();
                },
                buttons: [{
                    label: 'Add Comment',
                    action: function () { addComment(); },
                }, {
                    label: 'Close',
                    action: function (dialogItself) {
                        dialogItself.close();
                    }
                }]
            });